# Chart of 14-day cumulative rainfall

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart, precipitation, code-review

I need to chart/download a list of 14-day summed precipitation values, and I was not able to get this script to run. I seem to be running into an error related to the 'system:time_start' property. I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
var Park = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-42.602889166173824, -19.690269395136024],
          [-42.602889166173824, -19.75910638120446],
          [-42.5081320860957, -19.75910638120446],
          [-42.5081320860957, -19.690269395136024]]], null, false);

var roi = Park.geometry()

var START_DATE = "2016-01-01"; 
var STOP_DATE = "2022-01-01";

var rainfall = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate(START_DATE, STOP_DATE)

var list_dataset = rainfall.toList(ee.ImageCollection(rainfall.select('precipitationCal')).size());

var len = list_dataset.size();

var n = 14;

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), n);

var slicing_list = list.map(function(ele){
  
  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(n).int(); 
  
  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = list_dataset.slice(start, end);
  
  element = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(element)).sum();
  
  new_list = new_list.add(element);
  
  return new_list;

}).flatten();

var raincol = ee.ImageCollection(slicing_list.get(0))

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: raincol,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 100,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'
});

print(chart)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just getting memory errors. This is probably because you're turning your image collection into a list, something you should try to avoid. Something like this should work:

```
var windowDays = 14
var startDate = ee.Date('2016-01-01')
var stopDate = ee.Date('2022-01-01')

var rainfall = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startDate, stopDate)
  .select('precipitationCal')

var numberOfDays = stopDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var rainfallAggregates = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1), windowDays)
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var date = startDate.advance(ee.Number(dayOffset), 'days')
      return rainfall
        .filterDate(date, date.advance(14, 'days'))
        .sum()
        .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
    })
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8bbe290916f19d8cf80ca4a8e4ae0aa3